# Get all vertices or edges in a found cycle of a graph

Tags: cycle, boost-graph, undirected-graph

What I need is to store all the edges OR vertices that make a cycle found on a graph. After two days of search on web, the closer that I got is the code that is not working:

```
struct CycleDetector : public dfs_visitor<> {
CycleDetector(std::vector<Vertex> p, std::vector<Vertex>& _cycle) : m_predecessor(p), cycle(_cycle)  { }

void back_edge(Edge e, Graph const& g)
{
    Vertex t = target(e, g);
    Vertex c = source(e, g);

    std::cout << "(" << t << "," << c << ")" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Predecessor: " << m_predecessor[c] << std::endl;

    cycle.push_back(c);
    do {
        c = m_predecessor[c];
        cycle.push_back(c);
    } while(c != t);
}

protected:
std::vector<Vertex>& cycle;
std::vector<Vertex> m_predecessor;
};

int main()
{

//after a routine to create the graph and add_edges

std::vector<Vertex> cycle;
std::vector<Vertex> p(num_vertices(g1));
CycleDetector vis(p, cycle);

depth_first_search(g1, visitor(vis));

for (int i=0; i<cycle.size(); i++)
  std::cout << cycle[i] << ", ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Here is the output of the program. It's a spanning tree with max degree 2. I'm adding an edge on E and H vertices, to proposely create a cycle. I need to detect this cycle and return all the vertices or edges that form it.

Thanks.

[Output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ2Oa.jpg)

Comment: In your sample, you need to take `Graph& g` as `Graph const& g` to compile

Comment: Hi sehe. I made the change, and the code is running (sometimes for undefined time), but not giving the expected results. Can you give me some more help? I will post the output of the program.

Answer (score 1):

after a lot of search and attempts, I think I got what I need. I create a map to store the parent node of each node in a depth-first-search. For every tree_edge, I store the node and his parent. When the back_edge is called, I could detect a cycle and then, run throught the map of parents nodes.

I hope it may help

```
struct MyVisitor : default_dfs_visitor {
MyVisitor(EdgeSet& tree_edges, std::vector<Vertex>& _cycle) : tree_edges(tree_edges), cycle(_cycle) {}

void tree_edge(Edge e, const Graph& g) {
    std::cerr << "tree_edge " << e << std::endl;
    tree_edges.insert(e);
    Vertex t = target(e, g);
    Vertex c = source(e, g);
    m_predecessor[t] = c;


}
void back_edge(Edge e, const Graph& g) {
    if (tree_edges.find(e) == tree_edges.end()) {
        std::cerr << "back_edge " << e << std::endl;
        Vertex t = target(e, g);
        Vertex c = source(e, g);

        std::cout << "(" << name[t] << "," << name[c] << ")" << std::endl;

        cycle.push_back(c);
        do {
        c = m_predecessor[c];
        cycle.push_back(c);
        } while(c != t);
    }
}

private: 
   EdgeSet& tree_edges;
public:
   std::vector<Vertex>& cycle;
   map<Vertex, Vertex> m_predecessor;
};

int main() {

//routine that add the edges and other things

EdgeSet tree_edges;

std::vector<Vertex> cycle;
MyVisitor vis(tree_edges, cycle);
depth_first_search(g1, visitor(vis));

for (int i=0; i<cycle.size(); i++)
  std::cout << cycle[i] << ", ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I hope that if someone can give a better way to solve that, please post another answer that it's of my interest.